# Nesting columns and rows with Bootstrap for many-input section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have five columns I want on the same row. Within each of these boxes there are numerous form inputs some of which need to be on the same line or otherwise organized as well.

I have been attempting to mix it together using Bootstrap's grid system but nothing I seem to do is working as intended. I thought I could just throw everything into a container, and then use nested rows and columns to achieve the desired effect.

For attached Bootply, the Firstname, Middle Initial, Last name, and Nickname are a great example of what I'm going for. I want the "Name & Address" section to be one column, and within that I want all of the information to be on 3 rows

http://www.bootply.com/HhszskhttD

Is Bootstrap grid layout the best way to approach? Do I just need to mess with the sizing of my inputs? I have also tried mixing in form-group-sm but that did seem to go in the right direction. I suspect where I'm using form-group in relation to the rows and columns is the root of my issue.

What's the best way I can perform this type of layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is perfect for this! I love (LOVE) the Bootstrap Grid System.

To do what you would like to do it is very simple. For the first row put `class="row"`. After that it is all easy stuff. Nesting is just how it seems, but I will explain a little bit:

Lets say I have the following columns: `col-xs-4, col-xs-4, col-xs-4`. Now in one of those columns I want to separate boxs, I would add the following: `col-xs-6, col-xs-6`. You just have to remember, if you are nesting rows, they add up too 12 always. So when I am adding two 50% squares to the `col-xs-4` it would be `col-xs-6` and NOT `col-xs-2` (`col-xs-2` would be 16.66%).

So nesting is very simple, and it is not as tough as it seems.

**EDIT**

Let me throw an example out for you! :)
http://www.bootply.com/4yFHVS5g9r
The Bootply above shows how simple nesting is.

**EDIT 2**

Another example:

http://www.bootply.com/nJQEzSzsU7

Also, each nested column has 15px margin.

Comment: Thanks @Michael I appreciate the response. Given my bootply at http://www.bootply.com/HhszskhttD how do you recommend I can get the 5 fields (checkbox, firstname, m.i., lastname, nickname) to appear on the same row within how it's setup there?

Comment: @JoshuaOhana, do you mean all of them in the same width that the `First Name` is currently? Like all 5 inputs crammed into that area?  Well let me just do a Bootply, like this: http://www.bootply.com/M2CgED0LxS? (Fixed the link)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I meant... obviously needs lots of styling to make it look right but I was struggling how to even achieve the layout. Much appreciated @Michael

Comment: Yep, and remember, all nested columns have 15px margin on each side.